# Query sql para buscar e uma string igual porém maior que a que está armazenada na tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, mysqli

Eu tenho uma tabela que guarda urls de telas do meu sistema, eu queria realizar uma query que me retornasse uma url que vem parametrizada da seguinte forma `/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2` para essa url que está armazenada assim `/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/`, tentei usar o like mais não deu muito certo:

```
SELECT * FROM fogasdigital.TelaPerfil where url like ('%/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2%');
```

porque aparentemente o like só funcionaria se a url fosse menor que a que está armazenada, mais infelizmente não tenho como trazer ela reduzida do backend, também tentei usar o in mas também não obtive sucesso. O que está impatando é esse 2 que vem do sistema.

Comment: A URL está gravada como /avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/ e você precisa retornar ela como /avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2? O dois nessa história, não está presente no banco de dados, você só precisa para o retorno?

Comment: A url `/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/` é a que está no banco e a url `/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2` é o parametro de busca `SELECT * FROM fogasdigital.TelaPerfil where url like ('%/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2%');`

Answer (score -2):

Você tem algums formas de normalizar sua string para comparacação.

A primeira seria no próprio SQL usando uma especie de LastIndexOf no T-SQL:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2'),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE('/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2')),len('/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2')))
```

A segunda seria em sua aplicação ou TSQL também, removendo o último char com o substring:

```
SUBSTRING('/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2', 1, LEN('/avaliacoes-cozinha-segura/avalia-cozinha/2') - 1)
```

Mas creio que provavelmente você perderá performance comparando strings em seu sistema, talvez seria legal você repensar seu código.